# Cannot find DataContractJsonSerializer from an Asp.Net Mvc application

Tags: asp.net-mvc, json, serialization, namespaces, jsonserializer

I can't get access to the `DataContractJsonSerializer` method from `System.Runtime.Serialization.Json`

If I do:

```
using System.Runtime.Serialization.Json;
```

I get an error...

How can I access this in my Asp.Net Mvc app so I can use the `DataContractJsonSerializer`  method

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Make sure you've referenced the DLL where this type lives: System.ServiceModel.Web.dll

Comment: I did that and it still can't find it: http://screencast.com/t/IOEUsdN1E any other suggestion?

Comment: @Carlo, "The MSDN docs for .NET 3.5 incorrectly state that DataContractJsonSerializer lives in System.Runtime.Serialization.dll. This is true in .NET 4, but in 3.5 it's found in System.ServiceModel.Web.dll." - Ref: Comment by LukeH - [URL](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3178218/using-the-wcf-datacontractjsonserializer-in-net-3-5)

Answer (score 0):

Right Click in Project, Add Reference...

Search for **System.Runtime.Serialization**

Click Ok/Add