# How do I know what reference to include to import a specific .NET namespace?

Tags: c#, .net

This is in reference to [a problem I had](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1127264/cannot-find-datacontractjsonserializer-from-an-asp-net-mvc-application/1131227#1131227) which I was able to find the solution to here on Stack Overflow.

This wasn't my question, but it was the same exact problem I had. How do I know that I need to import a specific DLL file to use a specific namespace? I saw no reference to this on either the MSDN page or the Object Explorer, and even [ReSharper](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ReSharper) didn't pick up on it. Is this referenced anywhere?

Comment: Type the exact name of the class on google.com/bing.com and you'll get the link to the article guiding you to the assembly you require :)

Comment: Ideally, as John rightly said, it's on MSDN where you can find out details about the assembly, so just include MSDN as a keyword - for e.g. DataContractJsonSerializer msdn.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.json.datacontractjsonserializer.aspx:

## DataContractJsonSerializer Class

Serializes objects to the JavaScript Object Notation (JSON) and deserializes JSON data to objects. This class cannot be inherited.

Namespace:  [System.Runtime.Serialization.Json](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.json.aspx)
Assembly:  System.ServiceModel.Web (in System.ServiceModel.Web.dll)

Comment: Hmm, guess I'm blind. Thanks. Still wish there was an in-IDE solution though.

Comment: Just bring up the Help in the IDE.

Comment: If you open the object browser, search the type and it comes up, you can right click it, and choose "Go to definition". Then work back to the top level for the class to find the assembly it is defined in.

Comment: Yeah, I almost added that comment. Problem is he doesn't have the assembly referenced, so info on the type won't be there.

Comment: Depends where it is referenced... I find there's a whole bunch of assemblies in the object browser that I don't reference directly (perhaps they are dependencies of what I have referenced, I don't know). MSDN will always know though.

Answer (score 0):

Good question.  I generally do a quick search for the class on Google, then start typing for the assembly based on the beginning of the namespace it's in.

Answer (score 0):

When you look up the namespace on MSDN, most classes specify the assembly where it resides.

In reference to your previous question:
[MSDN Reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.json.datacontractjsonserializer.aspx)

Near the top you get your answer:

```
Namespace:  System.Runtime.Serialization.Json
Assembly:  System.ServiceModel.Web (in System.ServiceModel.Web.dll)
```