# How to find an assembly name for a .NET namespace, for example, Microsoft.WindowsAzure.ServiceRuntime

Tags: .net, azure, .net-assembly

I have a generic question, and specific example. This should be easy according to all the similar questions on Stack Overflow regarding assemblies for namespaces. The most common answer is found in question *[How do I know what reference to include to import a specific .NET namespace?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1165462)*.

"All MSDN doc pages mention namespace and assembly."

However on this MSDN page there is no mention of the assembly. What obvious thing am I missing?

[Microsoft.WindowsAzure.ServiceRuntime Namespace](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.windowsazure.serviceruntime.aspx)

Revised:

More specifically I'm looking for the DLL file to include for the Azure class RoleEnvironment. When I hit <kbd>F1</kbd> and look on its MSDN page [MSDN RoleEnvironment](http://msdn.microsoft.com/query/dev10.query?appId=Dev10IDEF1&l=EN-US&k=k%28ROLEENVIRONMENT%29;k%28TargetFrameworkMoniker-%22.NETFRAMEWORK,VERSION=V4.0%22%29;k%28DevLang-CSHARP%29&rd=true), it mentions the Microsoft.WindowsAzure.ServiceRuntime Namespace, but no assembly to include. I've run into things like this before, so I thought I would make it a generic question. Although I do want to know the specific DLL file to reference, I ALSO want to know the answer so I know what to do next time I face this situation.

Comment: When I load the RoleEnvironment page, right under the line giving the type's namespace, it says "Assembly: Microsoft.WindowsAzure.ServiceRuntime (in microsoft.windowsazure.serviceruntime.dll)"

Comment: ahhh, somehow I was looking at the Members page, and not the Class page.  There it is, right at the top.  Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Namespaces don't have assemblies. One namespace can be (and often is) in several assemblies. But specific types are in specific assemblies. So, if you look at the documentation for some type from the namespace you are interested in, you will see in what assembly that type is.

Other types from the same namespace are likely to be in the same assembly, but don't have to be.

Comment: Thanks for your response.  Please see revised question.

Comment: A specific example: System.Collections.Generic.List<T> is found in mscorlib.dll, while System.Collections.Generic.SortedSet<T> is found in System.dll

Answer (score -1):

Namespace: Microsoft.WindowsAzure.ServiceRuntime
Assembly: Microsoft.WindowsAzure.ServiceRuntime (in microsoft.windowsazure.serviceruntime.dll)

[RoleEnvironment](http://msdn.microsoft.com/query/dev10.query?appId=Dev10IDEF1&l=EN-US&k=k%28ROLEENVIRONMENT%29;k%28TargetFrameworkMoniker-%22.NETFRAMEWORK,VERSION=V4.0%22%29;k%28DevLang-CSHARP%29&rd=true)