# Using the WCF DataContractJsonSerializer in .NET 3.5

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, .net-3.5, datacontractserializer

I'm trying to use the geocoding code from here in my ASP.NET MVC 2 site. Unfortunately, some of that code, specifically **the DataContractJsonSerializer usage, is only possible through .NET 4.0**. As my hosting provider doesn't support .NET 4, I'm forced to implement that functionality in .NET 3.5.

**How can I rework the code (which I have reposted below) to work in .NET 3.5?**

The Google Maps Geocoding API can also return XML, if that's easier to serialize in 3.5...

---

Below is the code I'm trying to convert from .NET 4 to .NET 3.5:

```
using System;
using System.Runtime.Serialization;
using System.Runtime.Serialization.Json;
using System.Net;
using System.Web;

.
.
.

private static GeoResponse CallGeoWS(string address)
{
        string url = string.Format(
                "http://maps.google.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address={0}&region=dk&sensor=false",
                HttpUtility.UrlEncode(address)
                );
        var request = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create(url);
        request.Headers.Add(HttpRequestHeader.AcceptEncoding, "gzip,deflate");
        request.AutomaticDecompression = DecompressionMethods.GZip | DecompressionMethods.Deflate;
        DataContractJsonSerializer serializer = new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(GeoResponse));
        var res = (GeoResponse)serializer.ReadObject(request.GetResponse().GetResponseStream());
        return res;
}

[DataContract]
class GeoResponse
{
        [DataMember(Name="status")]
        public string Status { get; set; }
        [DataMember(Name="results")]
        public CResult[] Results { get; set; }

        [DataContract]
        public class CResult
        {
                [DataMember(Name="geometry")]
                public CGeometry Geometry { get; set; }

                [DataContract]
                public class CGeometry
                {
                        [DataMember(Name="location")]
                        public CLocation Location { get; set; }

                        [DataContract]
                        public class CLocation
                        {
                                [DataMember(Name="lat")]
                                public double Lat { get; set; }
                                [DataMember(Name = "lng")]
                                public double Lng { get; set; }
                        }
                }
        }
}
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

What is the specific problem that you're hitting?

Without more details it's difficult to diagnose the exact problem, but `DataContractJsonSerializer` *is* available in .NET 3.5 - you'll need to manually add a reference to *System.ServiceModel.Web.dll*.

(Note that the MSDN documentation misleadingly states that `DataContractJsonSerializer` can be found in *System.Runtime.Serialization.dll*. While this is true for .NET 4, the .NET 3.5 version of `DataContractJsonSerializer` actually lives in *System.ServiceModel.Web.dll*.)

Comment: Weird... I did add a reference to version 3.0 of that DLL, but it tells me it still can't find the type - and as for using statements, I have one that references System.Runtime.Serialization. What gives?

Comment: @Maxim: Try `using System.Runtime.Serialization.Json;`

Comment: @LukeH when I do that it tells me that it "can't find that namespace or type." I'm pretty sure it's something with my assembly references; is v3 the right version of the DLL?

Comment: @Maxim: Apologies. The MSDN docs for .NET 3.5 incorrectly state that `DataContractJsonSerializer` lives in *System.Runtime.Serialization.dll*. This is true in .NET 4, but in 3.5 it's found in *System.ServiceModel.Web.dll*. (I'll update my answer accordingly.)

Comment: Thanks @LukeH I was looking for the dll too, good to know that it's in System.ServiceModel.Web.dll

Comment: well it is available in both System.Runtime.Serialization.dll as well as in System.ServiceModel.Web.dll. [link] (http://forums.silverlight.net/post/47045.aspx)

Comment: Instead of using System.Runtime.Serialization.dll/ System.ServiceModel.Web.dll switch to NewtonSoft.Json library